# Java: Best practice/Design pattern for handling NULL cases on variables that SHOULD NEVER be NULL?

Tags: java, exception, design-patterns, error-handling, null

I asked everyone and generally have gotten different responses from everyone.

Now, having a variable that could be `NULL` in, say, Java, requires to handle that case generally speaking. We can do something like:

```
if(myVarThatCouldBeNull != null) {
   myVarThatCouldBeNull.getSomeValueFromMyVarThatCouldBeNull();
}
```

...Such that the getter method is only called when the var has a value (else a Null Pointer Exception (NPE) would be thrown).

My question is, for variable that absolutely should never be `NULL`, say you have an Attendance application (let's call it **API X**) that is used to automate taking attendance in school. You could have a `Student` model/object like such:

```
public class Student {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String email;
   private Integer id;
}
```

... Now we could assume or say, that in-order for students to have their attendance "logged", **API X** reads/consumes the fields/properties of the `Student` model/object as JSON key/value pairs POST'd from some API (we'll call this **API Y**). *API X* then deserializes the request from the API.

Since we already said the `id` is needed to log attendance, and a core-functionality of **API X**, it ***should never*** be `NULL`. This can be because, maybe there is a UI webpage with an input form to create the student account, and the `id` field is a *required* input field where students enter in their `id` from their school ID, else they **cannot** complete registration (no user account is created, thus no data sent to the backend applications, in this case, **API X** which would consume the request).

My question therefore is - In these cases (the latter), should developers/devs still be null checking the `id` field? My first thought is that it is *redundant*, but then again, it's only the developers assumptions that it is not needed. What if there is an edge-case out there that will break the API (API X), that we, the developer/dev is unaware of and because we are relying on our assumptions (and not fully committing to null-checking every variable), we would run into issues later on?

Then again, I could also see (and have seen) a codebase with `if(...)` wrapper functions for `NULL` checks as being unnecessarily verbose, and obfuscates the codebase and flow.

If everyone just assumed certain things didn't need null checks, I feel as if no-one would do null checks. But, is it really necessary to  wrap variables with conditionals e.g. if-statements, like ones in this example involving an `id` that is input by a user on a UI input form, and that the student account **cannot** be created without that `id` being input at the UI level? (backend systems would consume this later on downstream)?

I potentially overcomplicated this, but I was generally curious, would love to hear everyones responses

Comment: Tip: [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)), [`Objects.isNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#isNull(java.lang.Object)), and more.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot trust data sent from user, never

usually you have multiple layers in application:

1. controller which is actually accepts user input and should perform validation, including all null/not null checks
2. internal class which actually performs some work - this one can rely on upper level to supply valid data and thus omit validation

Comment: And another layer is validation checks performed within the database system.

Comment: @BasilBourque yep, each border between different systems should be guarded

Answer (score 0):

All client-facing API (the same is valid for libraries if they have restrictions on incoming data/setup/etc.) should perform validation on incoming data (even if the client is actually another service in your system in case of distributed ones). What is absolutely evident for your can be not that clear/evident to another user/developer even if we discard malicious intentions.

After the incoming data was validated though - it depends on how your application is written and structured, but there you can lax the checks, at least to some extent (i.e. usually there is less sense to revalidate already validated data).